# Need not replaced Latex code in href url

Tags: href, pylatex

In my document for making url to math search website I need to produce urls like this:

```
https://website.xyz/search/?q=%24\frac{\pi r^2}{2}%24
```

I'm using pylatex and I see that it generates tex code as I expect:

```
\href{https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24\frac{m^2}{s}%24}{$\frac{d m_s}{ct^{2}}$}
```

But in resulting pdf I get modified url:

```
https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24\protect {\begingroup m^2\endgroup \over s}%24
```

And here's python code to generate it:

```
formula_with_href = pl.NoEscape('\\href{https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24' + '\\frac{m^2}{s}' + '%24' + '}{' + '$' + formula_latex + '$' + '}')
```

The script is too large to display, so here's mimimized LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document} 
\href{https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24\frac{m^2}{s}%24}{$\frac{d m_s}{ct^{2}}$} 
\end{document}
```

So the question is how to make proper url.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Or, in your case, a runnable python script, that demonstrates the issue at hand...

Comment: Your code is still not minimal, anyway...

Comment: The problem is that I don't know for now what can be deleted from latex code

Comment: Almost everything ;) -- This code would be sufficient to demonstrate your problem: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24\frac{m^2}{s}%24}{$\frac{d m_s}{ct^{2}}$}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `\href` to work, you have to encode the url in [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), which python can do for you with `urllib.parse`:

```
import urllib.parse

domain = "https://approach0.xyz/search/?q="
formula = r"$\frac{d m_s}{ct^{2}}$"
query = urllib.parse.quote(formula)
formula_with_href = r"\href{" + domain + query + "}{" + formula + "}"
```

Which results in the correctly escaped string: `\href{https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bd%20m_s%7D%7Bct%5E%7B2%7D%7D%24}{$\frac{d m_s}{ct^{2}}$}`

[image]

If you click on the formula, the website opens correctly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked.